# How to forward internet connection in QEMU?

Tags: networking, qemu, openwrt, mips

Following the description on how to start an [OpenWrt VM with QEMU](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/virtualization/qemu), I downloaded the [MIPS kernel](https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/22.03.3/targets/malta/be/) and started it with this command:

```
qemu-system-mips -kernel openwrt-22.03.3-malta-be-vmlinux-initramfs.elf -nographic -m 256
```

However there is no internet connection in the VM:

```
root@(none):/# ping google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'
```

How could the host internet connection be used in QEMU?

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments, `ping` will not work because it uses ICMP. However, when using `wget` the following error occurs:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# wget http://google.com/
Downloading 'http://google.com/'
Failed to send request: Operation not permitted
```

The network configuration looks like this:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ifconfig
br-lan    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fd02:a553:49cb::1/60 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1248 (1.2 KiB)  TX bytes:2822 (2.7 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1290 (1.2 KiB)  TX bytes:2822 (2.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:10 Base address:0x1060

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:40288 (39.3 KiB)  TX bytes:40288 (39.3 KiB)
```

Comment: perhaps read [this part of the documentation you linked to](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/virtualization/qemu#provide_internet_access_to_openwrt)

Comment: @JaromandaX In the documentation the part about `vlan` is outdated. I tried using `-net nic -net user`, but this has no effect.

Comment: try a TCP based connection test, curl, wget, ssh. ping/ICMP uses raw sockets, and per the documentation does not work with net user.

Comment: huh? you have no `-net` in your question **at all**

Comment: So as Rui F Ribeiro wrote, it defaults to user mode: https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Network_Basics ("as if you had typed `-net nic -net user` on your command line"). and also as already told: "if you are using the (default) SLiRP user networking, then ping (ICMP) will not work, though TCP and UDP will. Don't try to use ping to test your QEMU network configuration!"

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro @A.B I updated the answer where now I try to use `wget`.

Comment: seems you are not getting a DNS configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As OP didn't provide any network setting:

> ```
> qemu-system-mips -kernel openwrt-22.03.3-malta-be-vmlinux-initramfs.elf -nographic -m 256
> ```

this will select the minimal user mode, as described in [QEMU's Network Basics](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Network_Basics):

> There are two parts to networking within QEMU:
>
> - the virtual network device that is provided to the guest (e.g. a PCI network card).
> - the network backend that interacts with the emulated NIC (e.g. puts packets onto the host's network).
>
> There are a range of options for each part. **By default QEMU will
> create a SLiRP user network backend and an appropriate virtual network
> device for the guest (eg an E1000 PCI card for most x86 PC guests), as
> if you had typed `-net nic -net user` on your command line.**

The [user mode network](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/devices/net.html#using-the-user-mode-network-stack) is seen like this from the VM's point of view:

> ```
> guest (10.0.2.15)  <------>  Firewall/DHCP server <-----> Internet
>                       |          (10.0.2.2)
>                       |
>                       ---->  DNS server (10.0.2.3)
>                       |
>                       ---->  SMB server (10.0.2.4)
> ```

QEMU can handle TCP, UDP and some but not much more like a DHCP and a DNS server. In particular this doesn't handle ICMP:

> Note - if you are using the (default) SLiRP user networking, then `ping`
> (ICMP) will not work, though TCP and UDP will. **Don't try to use `ping`
> to test your QEMU network configuration**!

It does so by tracking packets and using sockets on the host to emulate VM's behavior: when the VM sends a packet, QEMU opens a socket to send the same (it's of course more complex, especially with TCP). Actually the VM's source IP address is mostly ignored.

With the VM's OS intended to run a router, it doesn't know about this, and follows its default setup, which is apparently:

- doesn't use DHCP
- sets `eth0` as a bridge port to `br-vlan`
- assigns a static IP address to `br-vlan`: 192.168.1.1/24

As there's no default route, the VM won't attempt to communicate: it knows there's no route for this.

Had it used DHCP, it would have received this address on `eth0` 10.0.2.15/24 with a default route using 10.0.2.2 as gateway: those are the default values used by the user mode network stack emulation.

So the minimal equivalent command to run to have such default route using the proper gateway in the current setup is:

```
ip route add default via 10.0.2.2 dev br-lan onlink
```

(`onlink` skips the step of adding a route to 10.0.2.2 first). The same thing could have been done with eth0 by ditching `br-lan` first:

```
ip link del br-lan
```

and then:

```
root@OpenWrt:/# udhcpc -i eth0
udhcpc: started, v1.35.0
udhcpc: broadcasting discover
udhcpc: broadcasting select for 10.0.2.15, server 10.0.2.2
udhcpc: lease of 10.0.2.15 obtained from 10.0.2.2, lease time 86400
udhcpc: ip addr add 10.0.2.15/255.255.255.0 broadcast + dev eth0
udhcpc: setting default routers: 10.0.2.2
```

This won't configure DNS (`udhcpc` appears too limited for this). So in addition:

```
echo nameserver 10.0.2.3 > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Which now allows to do for example:

```
root@OpenWrt:/# wget http://google.com/
Downloading 'http://google.com/'
Connecting to 142.250.76.110:80
Redirected to / on www.google.com
Writing to 'index.html'
```

This won't go far. This won't allow to test the router features.

---

For more, one has to configure adequately all the network parts, possibly providing multiple NICs to the VM for adequate use. Reading further QEMU documentation. It should most certainly use the [TAP networking backend](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Tap). This requires to understand [how to do the configuration](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/devices/net.html#linux-host):

> See [Invocation](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/invocation.html) to have examples of command lines using the TAP network interfaces.

This requires the hypervisor system running the VM to have already configured proper network itself, so it can supply (with adequate network options) some of these resources to the VM.

For example running this command as root will provide 2 NICs in the VM:

```
qemu-system-mips \
    -kernel openwrt-22.03.3-malta-be-vmlinux-initramfs.elf \
    -netdev tap,id=n1,ifname=tapn1 -device pcnet,netdev=n1 \
    -netdev tap,id=n2,ifname=tapn2 -device pcnet,netdev=n2 \
    -nographic -m 256
```

One can then attach the 2nd NIC to an existing bridge on the host, for example, if one is also using LXC, to `lxcbr0`:

```
ip link set tapn2 master lxcbr0
```

Some other QEMU options probably can do this from the single command invocation. Likewise using some privileged QEMU helpers can allow to run the command as non-root again.

As LXC already provides DHCP (and DNS) on `lxcbr0`, this then allows to use DHCP in the VM:

```
udhcpc -i eth1
```

and then even something like `ping 8.8.8.8` will work, as long as the host provides connectivity. DNS still has to be configured manually like in the previous example.

Of course one should instead use OpenWRT's own configuration methods.